# compile error on android

Tags: android

In file included from

```
/home/imagetech/Android/android-ndk-r3/build/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/stdio.h:55,

from test_cl.cpp:21:
/home/imagetech/Android/android-ndk-r3/build/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:88:

 error: conflicting declaration 'typedef unsigned int size_t'

/home/imagetech/Android/android-ndk-r3/build/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/machine/_types.h:44:

 error: 'size_t' has a previous declaration as 'typedef long unsigned int size_t'
```

Comment: Would you tell us some detail also.

Comment: i just include <stdio.h> in my .cpp file , and compile it .

Comment: can you give us the code. I think the problem is that you include sys/types.h. Please provide the code as well.

Comment: in my cpp file ,it just have one code : #include<stdio.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you try different name "size_t" since i think the same declaration is present in the _types.h file. so it is giving the conflict.